# Is there a way to get a flow diagram of activities for a given project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, mobile

The company I started working for recently gave me their current Android project to read and understand. I am having a really hard time which activity starts or intends to start which one, basically not being able to understand the flow of things (Apart from the launcher activity)

Is there an easier way to determine the activity flow of the application apart from searching for Intent calls in every file, each file being large no. of lines of code?

Comment: I think you should start with launcher `activity`, than checkout it's `layouts` , `onClick` events used within the `activity` , like wise you will get and understand the whole flow of an application.

Answer (score 1):

Can you build and run the app so you can see and feel what different screens do?

Find main activity in a manifest. Search in main activity `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`, navigate to the next one and so on. This way you can draw graph, you may try any scripting language to automate the process.

The project may have fragments, so you will have to find `FragmentManager` and `commit()`.

Comment: Not really. I am not able to get past the login screen, and the senior dev here doesn't remember the test credentials. I can't circumvent that as well because the authentication code is convoluted, it is done through a .net web service. The app is a beta version though.

Comment: Make a ticket for him =) Meanwhile find a function or variable that says authentication ok and add stub as it always ok. Try to search tests if any.